# Python: How to correctly create and destroy resources using the contextmanager descriptor pattern

Tags: python-2.7, contextmanager

I implement the creation and destruction of resources in the following way:

```
import weakref

class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.resource = object()  # sample resource creation

    def __del__(self):
        self.resource = None  # destroy resource but keep attribute (compare with 'del')

    def get_resource(self):
        """
        return a proxy of the resource so that only this context 
        instance holds a valid instance and can therefore destroy it 
        when it wants to no matter if another 'reference' is hold 
        elsewhere
        """
        return weakref.proxy(self.resource)

class ContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._context = None  # create attribute

    def __enter__(self):
        self._context = Context()
        return self._context  # make the context available in the 'with .. as ..' statement

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._context = None


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with ContextManager() as c:
        print(c.get_resource())  # do something with resource

    """
    although we have left the scope of the with statement this print
    still executes and a check with gc.get_referrers still shows the 
    references in use
    """
    print(c.resource)
```

My question relates to the last line of code:

**Why is the context and/or resource still available although the scope of the with-statement was left which should have called the __exit__ function?**

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong when I assumed a scope behavior I know from C/C++ to work with python as well. The solution to my problem is to return a weakref.proxy of the context:

```
def __enter__(self):
    self._context = Context()
    return weakref.proxy(self._context)
```